# How does React capture the props with `const props = this.props`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

I read the [article](https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/) written by Dan. In the example below

```js
class ProfilePage extends React.Component {
  showMessage = (user) => {
    alert('Followed ' + user);
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    const props = this.props;
    setTimeout(() => this.showMessage(props.user), 3000);
  };

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Follow</button>;
  }
}
```

Why `props` does not change when `this.props` changed, since both point to the same reference?

Comment: How are you changing the prop `user`?

Comment: @Blundering Philosopher, `user` is changed in the parent component, but I think it is not related to this question, so I leave it aside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`props` object is immutable, `this.props` reference may change with time in case new props are received.

It should be:

```
  handleClick = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const { props } = this;
      this.showMessage(props.user);
    }, 3000);
  };
```

Also, timeouts should be tracked to be cancelled at component unmount in order to prevent leaks and exceptions.

Comment: Hi, @estus, thanks for explanation. what confuses me is that `props` just a local valuable in a method, how React can make it immutable when `this.props` is mutable? And how can we simulate this in a plain js/ts program without React?

Comment: `this.props` is not mutable. This is guaranteed with Object.freeze in development mode. Each time props are received, new props object is assigned, `componentInstance.props = Object.freeze({ ... })`. You kept a reference to old props object with `const props = this.props`. You can check that it was changed inside timeout callback, `console.log(props !== this.props)`.

Comment: Thanks, now I figure it out what's going on